# Filter Option with select tag Vue/Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, filter, ejs

I have an array of objects in my Vue instance which consist of data from a MongoDB server, and an array of numbers which represents weeks. The Arrays looks like this:

```
courses: [
{Course: "A" Week: "1"}, 
{Course: "B" Week: "1"}, 
{Course: "A" Week: "2"}, 
{Course: "B" Week: "2"}
 ],

weeksInSemester: [1,2,3]
```

I display my data with ejs like this:

```
<div v-for="value in courses">
   {{ value.Course }}
</div>
```

So far so good. Now I want to be able to filter the results from an  tag like this:

```
<select>
  <option v-for="weeks in weeksInSemester">
     {{ weeks }}
  </option>
</select>
```

I have been working/looking around for some time now, and not been able to find any solutions. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-model` on the select:

```html
<select v-model="selected">
```

Create a computed to filter the courses by the selected value:

```js
computed: {
 filteredCourses() {
    if (this.selected) {
      return this.courses.filter(v => v.Week === this.selected);
    }
    return this.courses;
  }
}
```

Use the `computed` with the `v-for`:

```html
<div v-for="value in filteredCourses">
   {{ value.Course }}
</div>
```

Demo:

```js
/***** APP *****/
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      courses: [
        {Course: "A", Week: "1"}, 
        {Course: "B", Week: "1"}, 
        {Course: "A", Week: "2"}, 
        {Course: "B", Week: "2"}
      ],
      weeksInSemester: [1,2,3]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredCourses() { 
      if (this.selected) {
        return this.courses.filter(v => v.Week === this.selected);
      }
      return this.courses;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="value in filteredCourses">
   {{ value.Course }}
</div>

<select v-model="selected">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option v-for="weeks in weeksInSemester">
     {{ weeks }}
  </option>
</select>
</div>
```

---

**Edit for your question in comments:**

To add an "All" option, you can insert a static option whose `value` is the empty string, which won't pass the `selected` check:

```html
<select v-model="selected">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option v-for="weeks in weeksInSemester">
     {{ weeks }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Mhm Seems like it breaks after I added the static all value. It does not filter on the other weeks after this.

Comment: You may have added it wrong.  Copy and paste from the demo if that helps